# Getting database does not exist while trying to containerize python app with postgres db hosted on GCP

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to containerize a python app and it has a postgres db which is in GCP cloud. But when I build the app its throwing an error telling the database does not exist i am unable to understand what is happening i can connect to the database by using Dbeaver tool but when I run the docker file
the container is up but has some error logs. I have added the public ip of my laptop in gcp sql connections but unable to understand why it throws this error

---

I can see the logs that say

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, 
in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "test-instance" does not exist
```

---

Docker file which i used

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.9

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code

# Install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy project
COPY . /code/
```

---

settings.py file how i reach out to the gcp db

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'test-instance', 
        'USER': 'postgres', 
        'PASSWORD': 'abcder',
        'HOST': '35.224.136.9', 
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're confusing the Instance Name with DB name. Are you sure you're setting the right DB name and not the instance name?

Comment: Yes. I hope u are referring to value of name in database block which is present in settings.py? the value is db name which is test-instance this is what my postgres db is called in gcp

Comment: Issue was resolved it was cause the db i was confused with instance name and db name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, the OP was confusing the `Instance Name` with the `DB name` which are different things.

The `Instance` is the infrastructure (server) hosting the `DB Engine` and where the DBs are hosted.